# Making a lucene 2.3 index compatible with lucene 4

Tags: solr, lucene

I understand lucene 2.x indexes are not compatible with the latest version of lucene 4.0. However we have all our indexes indexed with lucene  2.3.

Now that we are planning to migrate to Lucene 4.0, is there any work around I can do, so that I can still read the 2.3 indices? Or is forgoing the older indices the only option?

P.S : Am afraid, Re-indexing is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

[lucene-400-alpha-at-long-last.html](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/07/lucene-400-alpha-at-long-last.html)

```
Pre-3.0 indices are no longer supported.
```

So you would need to reindex the contents, if are using the latest lucene version.

Comment: This is what I have found so far. Very bad work around, but still works. Upgrade all 2.x to 3.x indexes via this https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html and then use 4.0. This would be my last resort though.